# How to write query for this requirement as in body?

Tags: sql-server

I want to print the hacker_id, name and the total number of challenges created by each student. Sort your results by the total number of challenges in descending order. If more than one student created the same number of challenges then sort the result by hacker_id. If more than one student created the same number of challenges and the count is less than the maximum number of challenges created then exclude those students from the result.

Hackers table

[image: Hackers table]

Challenges table

[image: Challenges table]

I have tried this query

```
SELECT b.hacker_id
    ,a.name
    ,count(b.hacker_id)
FROM hackers AS a
INNER JOIN challenges AS b ON b.hacker_id = a.hacker_id
GROUP BY b.hacker_id
    ,a.name
ORDER BY count(b.hacker_id);
```

But I am not getting output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.hacker_id, ISNULL(count(c.challenge_id), 0)
FROM hackers a
LEFT JOIN challenges c ON c.hacker_id = a.hacker.id
group by a.hacker_id
```

With left join you will take all elements from left table ("hackers") and counting of challenges for each, if exist. if result of **count(c.challenge_id)** will be NULL, this will be replaced by 0 value

Comment: What if challende_id will be either null or zero? Also you should explain your query.

Comment: ISNULL(c.challende_id,0)